# stock prices in sql table output prices by symbol in columns

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I have a SQL table with stock prices with the following columns:

```
Symbol | Date | Price
```

I would like to get this data into a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date | AAPL_price | GOOGL_price | MSFT_price ....
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pivot the data.  If you know the columns, then you can do the pivot in SQL using conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       max(case when symbol = 'AAPL' then price end) as aapl_price,
       max(case when symbol = 'GOOG' then price end) as goog_price,
       max(case when symbol = 'MSFT' then price end) as msft_price
from t
group by date;
```

If you don't know the symbols, then you can:

1. Query the table to get the symbols.
2. Construct the query using these symbols.
3. Run the query.

Or, load the data into a data frame and do the pivot in Pandas.

Comment: That is amazing.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Didn't know how to search for this because didn't know the terminology of **pivot**ing data.  In case anyone else would find it helpful, here's the documentation also for how to do this in Pandas as Gordon alluded to: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html